# Remove directory and all subdirectories

Tags: go

This is what I tried:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Removing build directory")
    if err := exec.Command("cmd", "/S /Q", "RD", "c:\\build").Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error removing build directory: %s\n", err)
    }

    if err := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "mkdir", "c:\\build").Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error making new build directory: %s\n", err)
    }
}
```

And my output is:

```
Removing build directory
Error making new build directory: exit status 1
```

So I don't get any error when removing, but it doesn't delete anything.

Why is that ?

Comment: What happens when you call these commands directl?

Comment: If I type rd /s /q c:\\build in command prompt, it works.

Comment: Have you tried using exe.Command("cmd", "/S", "/Q", "RS", "C:\\build").Run ? I don't use Windows so I can't test any of this.

Comment: Use http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.CombinedOutput instead of Run. This way you will be able to display stdout/stderr from your child process. Hopefully, it will print good error message there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Removing build directory")

   c := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "rd /S /Q", "C:\\build")

    if err := c.Run(); err != nil { 
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }  


    if err := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "mkdir", "c:\\build").Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error making new build directory: %s\n", err)
    }

}
```